# Label break line if string is too big

Tags: python, string, tkinter, label

Is it possible for, in python + tkinter, to set a maximum number of characters per line in a label? I have a program that opens a Toplevel window with some information taken from other information the user gave in the past. It is unresizable, which is a probel because every now and then the window get's too small for the information, which is shown in labels, so I was wandering if I could set it to add a line break every 30 characters, for example.
I looked through some label documentation, but the only thing I found was the possibility to change the label's width, which is not what I need, since is basically hides every character after the 30th.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put in the linebreaks yourself, using [`textwrap.fill()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

```
import textwrap

labeltext = textwrap.fill(labeltext, width=30)
```

Answer (score 2):

The option you are looking for is `wraplength`, which sets when a label’s text should be wrapped into multiple lines. However, this parameter is given in screen units, while `width` is text units if the widget displays text (so you can't use 30 directly).

Comment: you can't easily use it directly, but it's easy to determine the width of a character in a given font with the `measure` method of a `tkFont.Font` instance.